# What coordinate system is this?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I have a spreadsheet with X, Y coordinates but I can't work out which format they are:

`X: 8582265.9675991` and `Y: 239737.22394892`

It should be roughly equal to these coordinates: 71.23'28"W 12.47'21"S (these are DMS).

I have tried converting UTM, and all others but I just end up in the Atlantic or near India.

I am aiming for `Manu National Park, Peru.`

Comment: Have you tried http://projfinder.com?

Comment: Notice that the X coordinate is in the millions. That is much too high for the "east" coordinate in a UTM system. It is, however, a reasonable value for the "north" coordinate. Plugging this into UTM zone 19 S puts you here: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/-12.81363/-71.39762

Comment: thank you @TurePålsson, that is exactly where I want to end up. How did you convert them to that, was there a link or R package that can be used?

Comment: I used PostGIS, because that is what I happened to have at hand. :-) There is probably some projection library for R, but I'm not very familiar with R so I can't give any details.

Comment: @TurePålsson please add your comment (4) as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting my old comment to an answer)

Notice that the X coordinate is in the millions. That is much too high for the "east" coordinate in a UTM system. It is, however, a reasonable value for the "north" coordinate. Plugging N=8582266, E=239737 into UTM zone 19 S puts you [here](http://openstreetmap.org/#map=18/-12.81363/-71.39762).

(Also: [XKCD 2170](https://xkcd.com/2170/))